# Using variables as part of variable name in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I want to name variable as `a_${v}`.

for example :  v can be 2013 2014

I am now declaring a variable to `a_${v}`

```
a_${v}=hI # a_2013 should be Hi

v=2014
```

so `a_${v}=Hello # a_2014` should be Hello

I tried using eval command though it is not throwing error while assigning a value but I am not able to extract the value of variable name

```
$ v=2013

$ eval a_${v}=Hi


$ v=2014

$ eval a_${v}=Hello

echo ${a_${v}}
```

is not working.. :(

I am using bash and I don't want to change the variable name i.e dn't want to assign the value to another value

Comment: @Pumbaa80 The question (and its answer) you quote is `bash` specific and it can be useful to have a portable, non-bash specific, answer to this question.

Comment: Simple: remove your last line and instead do these two lines: `varname=$(echo "a_${v}")` followed by `echo ${!varname}`. You're welcome :D I would add this as an answer but it won't let me :/

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate! Need answer for /bin/sh not BASH, and without using eval (if possible). None of the linked answers satisfy this.

Answer (score 11):

In bash you can do the below (note the exclamation mark syntax in the last line):

```
#!/bin/bash

a_2014='hello 2014'
year=2014
varname=a_${year}
echo ${!varname}
```

Comment: This small example has saved so much time - thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Parameter expansion is not recursive, therefore the text `${a_${v}}` is really `The contents of the variable whose name is 'a_${v}'`, and the shell complains that this variable name is not valid.

You can achieve recursive expansion with the `eval` command, as in

```
eval printf '%s\n' "\${a_${v}}"
```

To increase the readability and maintainability of your shell scripts, you should limit the use of such constructs and wrap them in appropriate structures. See [rc.subr](https://svnweb.FreeBSD.org/base/head/etc/rc.subr?view=markup) provided on FreeBSD systems for an example.

Answer (score 0):

In bash 4.3 also:

```
txt="Value of the variable"

show() { echo "indirect access to $1: ${!1}"; }

a_2014='value of a_2014'
echo "$txt \$a_2014: $a_2014"
show a_2014                    # <-------- this -----------------------+
                               #                                       |
prefix=a                       #                                       |
year=2014                      #                                       |
string="${prefix}_${year}"     #                                       |
echo "\$string: $string"       #                                       |
show "$string"            #$string contains a_2014 e.g. the same as ---+

echo ===4.3====
#declare -n  - only in bash 4.3
#declare -n refvar=${prefix}_${year}
#or
declare -n refvar=${string}

echo "$txt \$refvar: $refvar"
show refvar

echo "==assign to refvar=="
refvar="another hello 2014"
echo "$txt \$refvar: $refvar"
echo "$txt \$a_2014: $a_2014"
show a_2014
show "$string" #same as above
show refvar
```

prints

```
Value of the variable $a_2014: value of a_2014
indirect access to a_2014: value of a_2014
$string: a_2014
indirect access to a_2014: value of a_2014
===4.3====
Value of the variable $refvar: value of a_2014
indirect access to refvar: value of a_2014
==assign to refvar==
Value of the variable $refvar: another hello 2014
Value of the variable $a_2014: another hello 2014
indirect access to a_2014: another hello 2014
indirect access to a_2014: another hello 2014
indirect access to refvar: another hello 2014
```